# Have to click login button twice; Using vue-router and firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vue-router

I have setup up a router guard so when I login instead of my router pushing it to the dashboard the split second time it requires firebase to authenticate it thinks im not logged in and I have to wait and click the login button again.

Is there any way to wait for it to log in then the router pushes me to the dashboard.

Im new to this any help would be appreciated.

```
//routes 

export const routes = [
  {
    path: "/adduser",
    component: AddUser,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: "details",
    path: "/details/:id",
    component: User,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    component: Register,
    meta: {
      requiresGuest: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    component: Login,
    meta: {
      requiresGuest: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    component: Dashboard,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Dashboard,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: "editUser",
    path: "edituser/:id",
    component: EditUser,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  }
];

//the login function 

 emailLogin(email, password) {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(this.$router.push("/dashboard"))
        .then(() => {
          this.$store.dispatch("auth/login");
        });
    }

//the router guard

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      next({
        path: "/login",
        query: {
          redirect: to.fullPath
        }
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresGuest)) {
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      next({
        path: "/"
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the `then(this.$router.push("/dashboard"))` the push gives a promise which should be returned to an arrow function.

So the new login function would be:

```
emailLogin(email, password) {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.push("/dashboard");
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.$store.dispatch("auth/login");
        });
    }
```